# Dynamic Name for Database Table - Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to create dynamic name for my database tables. I declare variable and use it as my table name.

**ERROR: Incorrect syntax near '@sample'. Expecting '.',ID or QUOTED_ID**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SAMPLE]
    @name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sample nvarchar(50);
SET @sample = 'tbl_function_' + @name;

Create Table @sample
(
    id int not null,
    UserType nvarchar(50) null,
    paramater2 nvarchar(50) null
)
END
```

Is there any way to make my table name dynamic? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you would want to do this.  But, you can do it using dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SAMPLE]
    @name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = '
Create Table tbl_function_@name
(
    id int not null,
    UserType nvarchar(50) null,
    paramater2 nvarchar(50) null
)';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@name', @name);

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Why would you want to create a separate *table* for each `@name`, instead of just inserting rows with `@name` in a column?

Comment: Thank you it works now. Also thank you for your idea adding column @name to my table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SAMPLE]
@name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @sql varchar(4000);

SET @sql = '
Create Table tbl_function_'+@name+'
(
id int not null,
UserType nvarchar(50) null,
paramater2 nvarchar(50) null
)'

EXEC (@sql) 
END
```

Comment: some comments would be nice, otherwise it's just a code-dump

Comment: @Ted this is another way to get results not a code-dump